# Spring Boot Testing Application Yaml java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

I am new to testing the spring application, not sure how to test a application profiles defined **application.yml** in my spring boot app.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {WebApplication.class})
@WebAppConfiguration

public class ApplicationSettingsTest {
    @Test
    public void applicationPicksRightTeamProfile() throws Exception {
        WebApplication.main(new String[] { "--spring.profiles.active=FalconDev1" });
        String output = this.outputCapture.toString();
        assertThat(output, containsString("falcondev.io"));
    }

    @Test
    public void applicationPicksRightDefaultProfile() throws Exception {
        WebApplication.main(new String[0]);
        String output = this.outputCapture.toString();
        assertThat(output, containsString("defaultdev.io"));
    }
}
```

My first test appears to be passing, but the second tests is failed with multiple errors,

> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol-8090]]
>
> Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName():
>   "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1014)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.59.jar:7.0.59]
>
> Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use     at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException:
>   Unable to start embedded Tomcat servlet container     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:165)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed
>   state     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:159)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]

**EDIT:**
*application.yml*

```
server:
    port: ${port:8090}
```

I do understood that application has actually started on port 8090 and my second attempting to run again on the same port, which I don't want.

so how to tell in my tests to just load the application context rather starting the real application.Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: `WebApplication.main(new String[0])` - the following code doesn't create Spring context. You do call just `java` class. What functionality do you test?

Comment: well, my intention is to test the behaviour, when the application has no command line arguments passed. so i used new String[0].In this case i would like the default profile to pick up. which is picking up fine. But the problem is when i run two tests same time.

Comment: Use `Environment` for that. See documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html#getActiveProfiles--.

Comment: If you want to set profile before Spring init application you can use following example - https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/generators/server/templates/src/main/java/package/_ApplicationWebXml.java and https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/generators/server/templates/src/main/java/package/_Application.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will run spring boot embedded container with random port:

```
@IntegrationTest("server.port:0")
```

In order to set Spring active profile in test you can use `ActiveProfiles`annotation.

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
```

Set `spring.profiles.active` in application properties or via environment variable using `--spring.profiles.active=test`.

Spring contains [`Environment`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) bean. If you want to obtain profiles in your code you can use following code:

```
@Autowired
Environment environment;

String[] profiles = environment.getActiveProfiles();
```

The following code `WebApplication.main(new String[0]);` is  incorrect. You do actually run 2 Spring context.

Comment: thanks for reply. still getting the same issue.I am using the your code in the test class along with code i have pasted in my question.

Comment: i think the problem is both tests are running on same port resulting the error.I don't have problems with fetching the profiles though.

Comment: ok taking your point, so how can i test that my application picks up the "default profile" when no arguments passed?

Comment: Inject `Environment` and test values. Code above gives almost all what your need.

Comment: sorry what do you mean? don't i need to run the  WebApplication.main twice or not? one with profile and one without profile? may be my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Yes you don't have to do `WebApplication.main(new String[0])`. This is incorrect.  `@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {WebApplication.class})` has already taken care of that.

Comment: ok i will remove the line you said incorrect. so how does my second tests looks then ?applicationPicksRightDefaultProfile()

Comment: i just want ensure , that correct url being picked up and showed in console. I have followed your code where i can see the correct active profiles being picked up.  but this.outputCapture.toString(); returns empty string.

Comment: Share the code where you do print `falcondev.io` to console. It doesn't make any sense to test something in the output. Logging configuration might have changed over time and your test will fail under some circumstances.

Comment: probably you are right.since i was not confident enough to assert was trying to print the settings .  see the appSettings.getUrl() prints the url.
http://pastebin.com/4kkAn32N

Comment: You can easily inject your application `AppService` and `ApplicationSettings`  and assert all required properties.

Answer (score 1):

The problem hear is that you start by heands the Spring context with the instruction`WebApplication.main(....);`

The key point hear is that the test class asserts that you have a test context, that will be a Spring context for testing in this stage you don't have the embedded tomcat started for this I can suggest to use `@WebIntegrationTest` without `@WebAppConfiguration`.

In your case in the first test method you will have a Spring context for test and then you start another spring contest that start also tomcat to the `8090` port, after this the second test method heredity the test context, but in the test method you restart the context and another tomcat on the same port and in this stage you get the exception.

The `@IntegrationTest("server.port:0")` don't work because this annotation work on the test context and not on the context that you start on you heands.

The my advice is refactoring the your code in this way:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {WebApplication.class})
@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort = true)
@ActiveProfiles("FalconDev1")
public class ApplicationSettingsTest {

    @Test
    public void applicationPicksRightTeamProfile() throws Exception {

        String output = this.outputCapture.toString();
        assertThat(output, containsString("falcondev.io"));
    } 
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {WebApplication.class})
@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort = true)
public class ApplicationSettingsTest {

    @Test
    public void applicationPicksRightDefaultProfile() throws Exception {
        String output = this.outputCapture.toString();
        assertThat(output, containsString("defaultdev.io"));
    }
}
```

Two test classes that map the you two siute of test, in the first you can test the profile `FalconDev1` in isolation from the default and in the second the other profile. in this way you can benefit of the spring abstractions.

I hope tha this can help you

Comment: i have tried this, Though the it seems work isolated but i am getting same error when i run the both test classes from package.

Comment: did you have tryied with two separated test class?........... it is very strange becouse I don't have the your problem, pheraps the your error source isn't releated with the test class.............. I don't know fpr me this approch works, can you give more details about the configuration?

Comment: yes, the application is getting started on the same port when i run the two classes same time.

Comment: do you use maven for run the test?, and more over do you remove the WebApplication.main(..)

Comment: ha very important don't forget the randomPort = true on  WebIntegrationTestannotation

Comment: becouse otherwise you get the your exceptions

Comment: If you get again the exception please try with mvn clean package on the command line, some time ide don't works very well cache too mutch especialy eclipse,   again this kind of configuration works for me

Comment: I developed a poc for validate this my words

Comment: yes i am using the exact configuration you suggested. i use gradle : gradle clean test. in your poc are you using embedded tomcat? and running on port?

Comment: i will try with gradle

Comment: I had try even for gradle.... and it works for me............... probably the your problem was releated on other aspect of your configurations

Comment: sorry my mistake i haven't removed WebApplication.main(..) .how are you capturing output ??. as String output = this.outputCapture.toString(); returns empty string for me.

Comment: the my poc is different I don't have the your code for performing the same test. I had test the start context and I assure that the two test suit use a different spring profile. I suggest the refactoring written above becouse I'm confident that your problem was the context start and not the business, that I don't know and of that I don't have the code. the may case just call a hello service that respect to the profile had a different behavior. And ti works correctly for me

Comment: where appSettings.getUrl print the URL and i am asserting against that output. but output in the test returns empty. my code:
http://pastebin.com/4kkAn32N